# Finding angular $scope in firebug

Tags: html, angularjs, firebug

Can i see the angular-`$scope` in Firebug (i searched in the DOM Inspector) without typing

```
angular.element($0).scope();
```

in the console every time?

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension called [AngScope](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/angscope-simple-angularjs-s/). It allows you to inspect the scope in your web application. 
All you need is Firebug but you already have it.
I hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

`angular.element($0).scope();` shows the scope for currently picked element from inspector. To get desired element's scope, do like this:

```
 angular.element('button').scope();
 //replace button with your desired element as you do in normal css for eg. .my-class
```